# The type of array by definition in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've just read in the book "The C Programming Language" that array is not a variable and saw that assignment of array to pointers (and vice versa) can't be done as a result. So if array is not a variable then what is it?

Comment: The following code is valid `int a[10]; int *p = a;`, but you can't do `a = p;`.

Comment: Arrays can't be assigned into at all, and when they are assigned into something else they decay to pointers. This is un-like true 1st class objects, which variables are.

Comment: also interesting read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int numbers[] = {1,2,3}
```

`numbers` is not a variable, it is the array name which is nothing but the address of the first element in the array. To verifiy this, look at the address of `numbers` and the address of `numbers[0]` by doing this: `printf("%p and %p and %p", &numbers, numbers, &numbers[0]);` All the the three pointers will have the same values since `numbers` is nothing but the address of the first element in the array. Therefore `numbers` is not a variable that contain a pointer or a value since it does not have a dedicated address in the memory to store value in it.

However, look at this pointer variable:

```
int *pnumbers = numbers;
`printf("%p and %p and %p", &pnumbers, pnumbers, &pnumbers[0]);`
```

You will notice that `&pnumbers` has a different address in memory, and that's because `pnumber` has a dedicated address in the memory where it stores the address of the first element in the array `numbers`.

**Putting the code all together:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    int numbers[] = {1,2,3};
    printf("%p and %p and %p\n", &numbers, numbers, &numbers[0]); // Address of numbers, value of numbers, first element of numbers

    int *pnumbers = numbers;
    printf("%p and %p and %p\n", &pnumbers, pnumbers, &pnumbers[0]); // Address of pnumbers, value of pnumbers, first element of the array pnumbers is pointing to
}
```

**Output**

```
0xbfb99fe4 and 0xbfb99fe4 and 0xbfb99fe4 // All three have the same address which is the address of the first element in the array
0xbfb99fe0 and 0xbfb99fe4 and 0xbfb99fe4 // The first one is different since pnumbers has been allocated a memory address to store a pointer which is the first element of the array numbers
```

Answer (score 3):

Array is a data structure containing a number of values, all of which have the *same type* and array names are *non-modifiable* l-values(named memory locations)-- **it is addressable, but not modifiable**. It means that it can't be modified or can't  be the left operand of an assignment operator.

```
int a[10] = {0};
int *p = a;     //OK
a++             // Wrong
a = p;          // Wrong
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a placeholder. A symbol to represent a commonly used method of referring to a sequential section of memory.  It's not a variable all by itself.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int array[10];
  int value'
  int* pointer;

  value = array[0];   // Just fine, value and array[0] are variables
  array[0] = value;   // Just fine, value and array[0] are variables
  pointer = &array[0];   // Just fine, &array[0] is an address
  pointer = array;    // Also just fine 
  //Because the compiler treats "array" all by itself as the address of array[0]  
  //That is: array == &array[0]

  &array[0] = pointer   // ERROR,  you can't assign the address of something to something else.
  array = pointer;      // ERROR, array is not a variable, and cannot be assigned a value.

  //Also bad, but technically they compile and could theoretically have their use
  pointer = value;
  pointer = array[0];
  array[0] = pointer; 
  //Intermixing pointers and non-pointer variables is generally a bad idea.
}
```

`array` is often treated like a variable because it represents the adddress of (the first item in) that block of memory. But it's not a variable. It doesn't have it's own memory to store anything. People set pointers equal to 'array' because it's a handy convention, compilers know what that means, and it's pretty common.

Comment: `pointer = array[0]; // Just fine, array[0] is a variable`: No, this is not fine. `But it's not a variable.`: No. Its a variable.

Comment: What? yes it's a variaaaawhoa. What was I thinking... pointer  = array[0] is not fine, because it's a variable and not an address.  uuuuugggghh.

Answer (score 0):

array is a sequence of elements of the same type. if you assign a pointer to an array, pointer will point to the address of first variable from an array.

```
int a[10];
int *p;
int *p2;
p = a;
p2 = &a[0];
printf("%d\n", p == p2);
```

output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 I've just read in the book "The C Programming Language" that array is not a 
 variable and saw that assignment of array to pointers (and vice versa)
```

Vice versa is allowed... An array is like a constant pointer (you cant change the address it is pointing to). However, you can assign that address to a pointer.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
    int x[3] = {1, 2, 3};

    int *p = x;
    p[0] = 50;
    printf("%d", x[0]);
 }
```

Comment: There's significant differences between an array and a constant pointer.

Comment: maybe in other languages... not in c

Comment: In C an array is storage for a number of objects, whereas a pointer indicates where another object may be found. Typically the pointer takes 4 or 8 bytes; the array may take megabytes

Comment: yes, but if you use just the identifier for the array, in an assignment for instance, you get address of its first element...
In the code I've shown above, anything you do using the array x you can replace that for p... of course if you use sizeof the values will be different but what I meant is "treat an array just like a pointer whose address will never change"